# How to Make array of elements with type specified at run time

Tags: go, struct

I am trying to create a array of elements with a type known only at the run time (a pkg API gets to retrieve elements in json and convert to struct). I have a helper function something like below, which takes an interface as a param and trying to get the type of interface while calling make.

golang compiler doesn't seems to like it.

```
var whatAmI = func(i interface{}) { 
        a := reflect.TypeOf(i)

        //var typ reflect.Type = a

        b := make (a, 10)    //10 elem with type of i

        //b := new (typ)
        fmt.Printf ("a: %v b: %v", a, b)
}
```

prog.go:21:14: a is not a type

I tried various combinations of reflects but no help so far. 
This seems to me can be a common problem to run in to. How can I solve/workaround this?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Elasticsearch abstraction for queries. The query returns json which I want to convert to struct. The kind of struct is known only at run time.

Comment: @joe Do you want to create a slice of the given type, or do you want a slice of []interface{} with values of the given type?

Comment: i just want to get list/array of a given type. Basically i want this type to be passed in to a utility function and return a list/slice of that type as result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get the type for a slice given a value of the element type, `v`:

```
sliceType := reflect.SliceOf(reflect.TypeOf(v))
```

Create a slice with length and capacity (both 10 here).

```
slice:= reflect.MakeSlice(sliceType, 10, 10)
```

Depending on what you are doing, you may want to get the actual slice value by calling Interface() on the reflect.Value:

```
s := slice.Interface()
```

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/jcGCSEap3z0).

Comment: I think this is near best solution for the question. But it surprises me the level of implementation complexity in go for a seemingly simple requirement. I believe, for the practical purposes @xian Shu's answer above is better.

Comment: @joe  This answer creates a slice of the given type which I assumed you were asking.  If you want a []interface{}, then the other answer is correct.

Comment: @joe I agree that this is complex, but there's probably as simpler solution to whatever your higher-level problem is. Applications can usually rely on the json/encoding package to do all of the heavy lifting as far as reflection is concerned.

Comment: i just want to get list/array of a given type. Basically i want this type to be passed in to a utility function and return a list/slice of that type as result

Comment: The other answer does not create a slice of the given type. This answer does.

Answer (score 2):

Just make like :

```
b := make([]interface{}, 10)
for i := range b {
    b[i] = reflect.Zero(a)
}
```

Comment: Thanks !! I thought about doing this as a workaround with New(). But I thought there should be a way to do it in one step. I can do this in C in one step!!

Comment: @joe, I think there is no another simple way in go like in Js or java lambda. What you want to do is initializing a set object but not a simple obj, so, there is no syntactic sugar to complete your want.